# Laravel + basic auth except one folder not working

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I did some coding to get the nginx config file working.

My objective is to allow all `.well-known` folder and subfolders leaving the rest with basic auth, limit_req and laravel compatible.

The problem now with let's Encrypt is that it is not renewing the cert because the route `.well-known/acme-challenge/wPCZZWAN8mlHLSQWr7ASZrJ_Tbk71g2Cd_1tPAv2JXM` is asking for permission, probably affected by `location ~ \.php$`

So the question is: Can I integrate one solo function? like `~ / and \.php$ \.(?!well-known).*` And if so, can I integrate the code of both all together?

```
location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    limit_req   zone=admin  burst=5  nodelay;
    limit_req_status 503;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;

    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easy peasy

```
location / {
        limit_req   zone=admin  burst=5  nodelay;
        limit_req_status 503;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }

    location ^~ /.well-known/ {
        auth_basic off;
    }
```

I don't think it can be optimised

Answer (score 2):

Yo can try the following:

```
auth_basic "Restricted Content";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

location / {
    limit_req   zone=admin  burst=5  nodelay;
    limit_req_status 503;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}

location ^~ /.well-known/ {
    allow all;
    auth_basic off;
}
```

Not sure if it can be optimised tho

Comment: looks good but the route .well-known/acme-challenge/wPCZZWAN8mlHLSQWr7ASZrJ_Tbk71g2Cd_1tPAv2JXM is not auth off